# Upgrading from cocos2d v3.0 to v3.3 without SpriteBuilder

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I try to upgrade from v3.0 to v3.3 without Sprite builder as my current project has been started one year ago. I installer Sprite builder, opened a basic new project in xCode and copied the cocos2d files into the old project.

The files and folders I copied are these ones :

- cocos2d/
- cocos2d.xcodeproj
- cocos2d-ui/
- external/

I had to change the header search paths for chipmunk. It took me a while but I fixed all the issues.

Now I have another problem : xCode give me an error : "SSZipArchive.d, Dtrace error". Nowhere in my project I can find a file named like this.

Anyone has an idear about that ?

Comment: Its a headache to do it this way, because you need to update your paths appropriately in your project settings. I would recommend you to create a blank sb project and import all your source files from your old project into the sb project and start your scenes programatically instead of using ccbreader.

Comment: The process described here can also be applied to non-SB projects: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1e59NyyVyT4_NB5ePnMVDe_a57z46Ft1QdFjCnP4Eh54/edit?usp=sharing

If that doesn't help, please post the exact and complete error message, plus the code where the issue occurs.

Comment: Hi Johnny. Thank for your answer. I'm on what you said for 4 hours now and it's a headache too. I can't even figure out how to load a scene programmaticly from the AppDelegate (means to replace the MainScene by another one).

Comment: @LearnCocos2D : the doc you speak about is to support the SB Android Plugin. I only want to publish IOS app.

Comment: That's okay, the process described is only to make the project compatible with the latest SB that support Android development. But you can just ignore Android development, the documented procedure will make your project work with latest SB in general, that includes iOS development.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this template](https://github.com/slembcke/UnofficialCocos2DTemplate) for creating new Cocos2D projects without SpriteBuilder. Just run a few `git` commands and import your files.